# Store Cookie On Window UnLoad (Window.Variable)

Tags: javascript

**UPDATE:**

*I stopped using an array (As I originally was when I first posted this)*

---

I seem to be having issues with my script. I don't know why, but when the web page unloads, the window.SpecificURL doesn't save. I know the script to get it is fine, the script to store it is as well. Is there something I am missing? Here is my code:

```js
        var UWDV = window.UWDV = "UserWindowDataV2"; // What Version Is The User Window Data Stored As
        setTimeout(function(){ // Wait So Stuff Can Load
            if (!window.SpecificURL){ // If Not A Special URL To Load
                window.SpecificURL = GetCookie(UWDV); // Get The User's Last Known State
                var WSURL = window.SpecificURL; // Set Variable
                // if (typeof WSURL[0]!=="string" || WSURL[0].length < 2){SetCookie(UWDV, ["home"]); WSURL = ["home"];} // If It Glitched, Fix Automatically
                console.log(WSURL);
                fillpage(WSURL); // Load Page PC
                mobileload(WSURL); // Load Page Mobile
                window.SpecificURLReady = true;
            }
        }, 100);
        window.addEventListener("unload", function(){SetCookie(window.UWDV, window.SpecificURL);}); // Add Save Page Status Function
```

(FYI: The fillpage & mobileload functions set window.SpecificURL to whatever the choice was.)

(FYI2: This is fired 2 seconds after the website loads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I fixed it by switching from Arrays to save data, to a string. Sorry for any inconvenience to someone trying to solve this!**